# Exhaustively matching a range of integers involving a "larger than" case

Tags: rust

Consider a Rust program with a built-in integer constant `const N: u64` and a runtime integer value `x: u64`. I would like to match on `x` such that values `x < N` each get an individual special case. Additionally there should be a single case for `x == N` and one for `x > N` respectively. My first attempt looked like this:

```
const N: u64 = 3;

match x {
    0 => println!("Special case for 0"),
    1 => println!("Special case for 1"),
    2 => println!("Special case for 2"),
    N => println!("Equal"),
    _ => println!("Larger"),
}
```

This works, but it has the following shortcoming: Imagine I increase the value of the constant to `N = 4` but forget to add the new special case `x = 3`. The code above will not catch this at compile-time, because the last match pattern (`_`) covers the forgotten case too and the code breaks silently. So I'm looking for a solution that has this kind of compile-time guarantee.

To achieve this, the last case should only match `x > N` instead, so I tried using an `if` condition:

```
match x {
    0 => println!("Special case for 0"),
    1 => println!("Special case for 1"),
    2 => println!("Special case for 2"),
    N => println!("Equal"),
    _ if x > N => println!("Larger"),
}
```

But now I get an error from Rust that the match is not exhaustive, which I think is due to the compiler not being clever enough to analyze the `if` condition. It is clever enough to analyze ranges though, but I don't know how I can express that last case as a range. It would have to be something like `(N+1)..=u64::MAX`, but that does not actually compile because of the plus sign.

My best solution so far is using a nested match as shown below. This seems to work and also gives the desired compile-time error when `N` is changed, but I wonder if there is a more elegant solution to this.

```
match x {
    0 => println!("Special case for 0"),
    1 => println!("Special case for 1"),
    2 => println!("Special case for 2"),
    N..=u64::MAX => match x {
        N => println!("Equal"),
        _ => println!("Larger")
    }
}
```

Comment: "due to the compiler not being clever enough to analyze the if condition." Not quite; the semantics of match guards is that they are always considered fallible, even `if true`. The reasoning is that match guards that can't fail are usually pointless – you could just as well remove them. So the compiler _should_ not analyze the if condition, regardless of how smart it is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
match x {
    0 => println!("Special case for 0"),
    1 => println!("Special case for 1"),
    2 => println!("Special case for 2"),
    N => println!("Equal"),
    N.. => println!("Larger"),
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=release&edition=2021&gist=a51b55a8c32b4f1fab0dab755b602a46)